# How do you say status in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

As in a Twitter status, or 'tweet'. It shouldn't be used to refer specifically to a status on Twitter, though.

Answer (score 2):

It is a message, so *mesaĝo*. I don't see why it would need a specific new term.

Comment: Mi ne uzus tion. Oni eble pensus ke estas privata mesaĝo.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use "afiŝo" as not to mix up private messages and statuses.

Answer (score 2):

If it's in reference to one's current state, "stato" should be fine. But if you want to include in its meaning that it's being posted you may also consider "statafiŝo".